# Android List View force close error on scrolling the listview

Tags: android, listview, forceclose

I have a listview with images and text , which I use Efficient adapter ( customised adapter) to populate the listview . I have implemented pagination in list view .I am developing the app in Android 2.1 .When I am running the app in Android 2.1 phone it works fine .But when running on higher versions (Android 2.2 and above ) , on scrolling the listview it shows " Force close error "

Bellow I am pasting the error :-

```
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367): java.lang.StackOverflowError
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.getSpans(SpannableStringInternal.java:269)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.text.Styled.drawUniformRun(Styled.java:61)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.text.Styled.drawDirectionalRun(Styled.java:298)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.text.Styled.drawText(Styled.java:357)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:1387)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:370)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:365)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4050)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6500)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.View.getDrawingCache(View.java:6288)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1565)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1365)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3046)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6846)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2257)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
03-08 20:10:50.546: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.ja
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted any code, my best guess is that you have an infinite loop or recursive call somewhere that never terminates.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted any code, so it's hard to be certain.  However this seems to be a reasonably common problem if you're using `.append()` method on a `TextView` on your list item view.  If this is case, the solution seems to be to create the full text string in a variable and use `.setText()` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

It was driving me crazy. The solution for me was to reduce layers depth as much as possible. Where it is possible use RelativeLayout with views without other layouts. At first glance this does not seems to be a solution, but at less for me it was.